# React app not rendering CSS, i have added CSS file in index.html

Tags: css, reactjs

This is what i get when i view the page source and CSS file is also correctly linked and it opens stylesheet when clicked on the link, yet CSS is not being rendered on page. any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic issue change src to href it'll work. if you have a minute just glance @ Mozilla External Resource Link element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not embedding the source here. When you need to specify the source use => *href*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
    **<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />**
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./src/index.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```